# C++ destructor for tree structure

Tags: c++, tree, destructor

I have this tree structure:

```
public:
    node(string& const n);
    virtual ~node();
    string get_name() const;
    void set_name(string& new_name);
    int get_nr_children() const;
    node get_child(int i) const;
    void add_child(node child);
private:
    string& name;
    vector<node> children;
};
```

and my main.cpp looks like this:

```
int main() {
    string s = "root";
    node r(s);
    string s2 = "left child";
    node ls(s2);
    string s3 = "right child";
    node rs(s3);

    r.add_child(ls);
    r.add_child(rs);

    r.~node();
}
```

(I know that `~node()` is run on all objects anyway at the end of the `main` funciton, but I want to make sure it is executed on the root `r` first)

All methods are working fine so far, except for the destructor. This is my first destructor, and I came up with the following recursive try, but don't know why it won't work.

```
node::~node() {
    cout << "Enter ~node of " << this->get_name() << endl;
    while (this->get_nr_children() != 0) {
        this->get_child(0).~node();
        this->children.pop_back();
    }
    delete this;
    cout << "Leave ~node of " << this->get_name() << endl;
}
```

The result is an endless output of "Enter ~node of left child"

Comment: _`delete this;`_ Huh???? That's blatantly wrong!

Comment: Do *not* call destructors directly. Instead use `delete` (better yet: use containers or smart pointers).

Comment: Without seeing what `add_child` does all we can offer is speculation. Make a [mcve]. Also you access `this` right after `delete`ing it.

Comment: @crashmstr To note aside: **Certainly not with `this`!**.

Comment: But only call `delete` on pointers to objects that you allocate with `new`.

Comment: your structure only contains a vector and a reference, which are automatically destructed properly... So why write one?

Comment: `delete this` from within a destructor? REALLY?

Comment: `void main` has never been valid in either C or C++. Code with `void main` teaches beginners a bad habit and means most readers can't just copy and paste the code to try it out. Please don't post code with `void main`. Thank you. FTFY.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I upvoted your comment since it is indeed wrong here. But, there are situations where `delete this` makes sense. If an object knows it is no longer referenced by anyone and no longer serves a purpose (and was allocated on the heap - tricky) then it can commit suicide via `delete this` as long as no subsequent code references any member variables.  It *can* make sense, but if you write code like that I'd suggest you get your head examined...

Comment: @crashmstr i'll go ahead and try to implement smart pointers (tho i still have the inital fear of pointers, hehe). thanks for the hint.

Comment: @PattuX for smart pointers to even be relevant, you need to have pointers... which you don't seem to have at all. Your children are a `vector` of `node`, so there is no "cleanup" to do with `delete`.

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, I'll re-write `get_child()` and `children` to use pointers first.

Comment: Please go read a *good* book on C++. Then indent this code 6 feet down and cover it with dirt. It is horrible.

Answer (score 3):

> "(I know that ~node() is run on all objects anyway at the end of the main  funciton, but I want to make sure it is executed on the root r first)"

This quote is enough to say that everything into this question is based only on misconceptions.

It doesn't even make sense to try to correct: a full rewrite is necessary.

Instead read more about destrcuctors, their invocation and what they are for.

Calling it explicitly does not suppress the implicit call of it. And double destruction is undefined behavior.

Also `delete this` is something very tricky requiring you must be VERY SURE of what it means.

And accessing class methods (`this->...`) or data after deleting them ... is only looking for troubles.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid and yields Undefined Behavior if it compiles:

```
vector<node> children;
```

At the point of this data member declaration the class `node` is *incomplete*; its size isn't yet known.

You can't use an incomplete type as item type for a standard library container (but you can use pointers).

---

In the destructor implementation, also

```
delete this;
```

yields Undefined Behavior, an infinite recursion calling the destructor which (in this `delete` expression) calls itself, and so on.

---

The data member declaration

```
string& name;
```

also has a strong, unpleasant odour about it, but since you're not showing the constructor implementations I can't state categorically 100% that it's wrong.

However, given the rest of the code, the chance of this being correct is infinitesimal. Just use

```
string name_;
```

Comment: The first one is allowed in C++1z.

Comment: @T.C.; You mean it will most likely be supported in C++17. Thanks I didn't know. Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, a tree uses nodes that are allocated on the free store. That means trafficking in pointers to nodes, and deleting nodes that are no longer in use. The code in the question doesn't follow that model: it allocates the root node on the stack, and stores node objects rather than pointers within each node. With that code, all of the compiler-generated destructors will work just fine. There is no need for any user-defined destructors.